# Select data from table using REDISQL in Redis

Tags: php, sql, redis

I have install **Redis** in `Ubuntu 16.04.6` successfully.

Here is the demo code for set and get value in **redis**.

```
<?php 
    //Connecting to Redis server on localhost 
    $redis = new Redis(); 
    $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); 
   //set the data in redis string 
   $redis->set("tutorial-name", "Redis tutorial"); 
  // Get the stored data and print it 
  echo "Stored string in redis:: " .$redis->get("tutorial-name");
?>
```

And I have got correct output as below.

```
# php redis.php 
Stored string in redis:: Redis tutorial
```

Now I want to store some value in redis with SQL so I configure **Redis** with **RedisSQL** and it configures correctly and working fine with a command line.

I have create one DB and insert one record for testing.

Here is the output of the SQL select query in **Redis**.

```
# redis-cli -p 6379
127.0.0.1:6379>  REDISQL.EXEC DB "SELECT * FROM foo;"
1) 1) (integer) 3
2) "bar"
```

Now I want to try to get the same query result in PHP script so I search for this and find like using rawcommand to get command output in redis so I tried using the same command as below.

```
<?php 
    //Connecting to Redis server on localhost 
    $redis = new Redis(); 
    $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); 
    $result = $redis->rawCommand('REDISQL.EXEC', 'foo', 'SELECT * FROM foo;');
    echo "Foo table Data:";
    print_r($result);
?>
```

But get `$result` value blank.

```
# php redis.php 
  Foo table Data:
#
```

So can anyone guide me to get the correct result for SQL query, with rawCommand or any other command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a php, sql or redis problem? What kind of assistance do you need?

Comment: Problem in php, In redis it working correctly with command line but in php script there is no response of sql query using redis.

Comment: I see. My php knowledge is minimal, so I can't help you there.

Comment: @jarlh , Okay no problem, thanks for interest to solve my issue.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I have re-install redis and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the select statement in double quotes

```
$result = $redis->rawCommand("REDISQL.EXEC", "foo", "SELECT * FROM foo");
```